# Creating Private App Version for Company Employees on Apple App Store

Tags: ios, app-store

Hi Stack Overflow community,

I'm a mobile app developer looking for guidance on providing a tailored version of my application exclusively for employees of a specific company on the Apple App Store. The company has a user base of over 20,000 individuals.

I'm seeking advice on the best practices and steps to follow within the Apple App Store and developer guidelines to generate a private download link limited to this organization's employees.

Comment: I think you’re looking for the [Apple Developer Enterprise Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/). But these are not distributed via the App Store. They’re distributed directly to the devices.